# How to work with codepipeline in SAM project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-sam

I have a SAM project to deploy my app, I deploy this stack using `sam build` and `sam deploy`

I recently added a codepipeline (with all its resources) to the template. The problem is that when I deployed the app, code pipeline created another stack.

Is there a way to mantain only 1 stack?

If not I must separate them as nested stack o different stacks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TLDR; [Adding CodePipeline to a SAM app](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-generating-example-ci-cd-codepipeline.html) necessitates an additional CloudPipeline stack.

The Codepipeline stack is independent of the "app stacks".  This loose coupling is helpful:

1. Can deploy the app manually via `sam deploy` for testing, while using the pipeline for prod.
2. Can clone the app to multiple regions or accounts with [pipeline stages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/reference-pipeline-structure.html#pipeline-requirements)
3. Can add fancy test or approval [actions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/action-types.html) in the pipeline without touching the app code

(It also seems like this setup helps AWS avoid tricky chicken-and-egg dependency problems of having to bootstrap the pipeline before deploying on the app resources.)